# Inheritance : calling members and methods of the base class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I started understanding the inheritance concept in c++. We have this statement:

> The derived class inherits members and methods of the base class.

So, I run the following example to apply the above statement:

```cpp
    class A {
    public:
        int a;

        A(int val){a=val;}

        void afficher(){  cout << a <<endl; }

    };

    class B : A {
    public:
        B(int val) : A(val){};
    };

    int main(){
        A a(5);
        a.afficher();

        B b(6);
        b.a = 4;
        b.afficher();
        return 0;
    }
```

I got the following errors when calling the member `a` and the method `afficher()` by the instance `b` that contradicts the statement:

```
error: 'int A::a' is inaccessible

error: 'void A::afficher()' is inaccessible
```

My question : how to call members and methods of the base class by a derived instance?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance

Comment: yeah, basically a dupe of [Difference between private, public, and protected inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance)

Comment: Continue reading the book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as for members, the default accessibility of bases for a type declared with the `class` keyword is `private`. Therefore, your `B` inherits everything from `A` as private members, hence those errors.

Change it to `class B: public A`.